# Set up project relationships for the "Close Unrelated Projects" option in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In the Eclipse package and project explorer views there is a very helpful context menu option titled "Close Unrelated Projects".

The [feature description](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.2-200606291905/new_noteworthy/eclipse-news-part1.html) and [help pages](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-27.htm) don't say what unrelated means though:

> **Close Unrelated Projects**
>
> This command will close any project which are unrelated to the selected project.

Whenever I click on "Close Unrelated Projects", every single other project gets closed. I believe there should some way to "relate" projects so they are kept open, but I don't know how nor what exactly Eclipse's definition of *project relation* is.

I usually work with maven projects and modules. Is there any way to define a relationship between projects like this so they don't get closed? Or is there another way to group some projects and hide all others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to create relationships between projects and use the "Close Unrelated Projects" feature.

- In the project properties, under *Java Build Path > Projects* you can add currently opened projects.
- In the project properties, under *Project References* you can add any other project.

The relationship is only shown on one project but still works bidirectional. If you click on "Close Unrelated Projects" on either projects, the other one will still be open. Likewise opening either project prompts you to open related projects.

In a Maven project with modules, it seems best to set the relationships only on the parent project and not the other way around, to keep all references in a single place.

- Use working sets and use the "Close Unrelated Projects" option of the working set's menu instead of the project's menu. This will close all other projects, except those in this working set and projects in other working sets that are related to any project in this working set.

To view working sets, you can change the "Top level Elements" configuration of the *package explorer* view to "Working Sets":

[image: package explorer top level element configuration]

Relationships are chained: Given the three projects A, B and C, if A is related to B, and B is related to C, then A and C are also implicitly related and will be opened or closed together.